# Storing or modifying packages in SQL Server requires the SSIS runtime and database to be the same version

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have SSIS package installed and running perfectly on test server. I have installed this using package manifest file. However, when same package i tried to install on UAT its showing below error.

> Could not save the package "E:\UAT\csv_Files.dtsx" to SQL Server "uat".  (Package Installation Wizard)===================================Storing or modifying packages in SQL Server requires the SSIS runtime and database to be the same version. Storing packages in earlier versions is not supported.------------------------------
>   Program Location:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.SaveToSqlServerAs(Package package, IDTSEvents events, String packagePath, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Deployment.DtsInstaller.SavePackageToSqlServer(WizardInputs wizardInputs, String packagePassword, Boolean bUseSeverEncryption, String serverName, String userName, String password, String packageFilePath, List`1 configFileNames, String packagePath)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Deployment.DtsInstaller.InstallPackagesToSqlServer(WizardInputs wizardInputs)===================================
>   Storing or modifying packages in SQL Server requires the SSIS runtime and database to be the same version. Storing packages in earlier versions is not supported.------------------------------
>   Program Location:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.SaveToSQLServerAs(IDTSPackage100 pPackage, IDTSEvents100 pEvents, String bstrPackagePath, String bstrServerName, String bstrServerUserName, String bstrServerPassword)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.SaveToSqlServerAs(Package package, IDTSEvents events, String packagePath, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)

When I did few investigation, found that, both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 are installed on same server. And, this is what I'm expecting the possible cause. I also see that both SQL sever installation is pointing to same UAT server name. On few more search on net showed me two links below:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1529945.aspx?Installing+sql+server+2005+SSIS+packages+on+SQL+Server+2008+

http://sqlserverandme.blogspot.in/2015/05/solved-storing-or-modifying-packages-in.html

I tried 1st link but its not working and for 2nd link, as server name is same, so I gave "uat" ; however, its not working as well.

Both UAT and test are 64 bit server. And, SSIS solution is VS2008 BI studio.

Note: My deployment is SQL Server deployment.

when I do SELECT @@VERSION:-

**IN UAT - not working**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 18 2012 09:40:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

**IN TEST - working fine**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 18 2012 09:40:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

I'm not sure, what this "Hypervisor" means? Is this creating problem?

The Error screen:
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue? Or please guide me if anything else I can try to fix?

Comment: You have multiple instances installed?  You'll need to [determine the instance names of the servers running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions), and then connect to the 2008R2 instance.

Comment: I tried this to get instances, however, it shows me only one instance: InstalledInstances - Item #1    MSSQLSERVER     NULL          EXECUTE xp_regread
 at(%)rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
at(%)key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',
at(%)value_name = 'InstalledInstances'                                    I'll try again - the link you have provided.

Comment: That almost sounds like the SQL Server 2008 R2 instance was upgraded to SQL Server 2012.  You're going to have to figure out what's actually there.  I assume if you query the server with `SELECT @@VERSION` you get 2012.

Comment: With those command server name is coming as NONE. :(

Comment: No name = default instance, AFAIK.

Comment: No, I'm getting version as : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2). What does it mean by default instance ? Or do you think, the issue could be due to some other problem, rather than SQL Server Versions ??

Comment: "What does it mean by default instance ?"  That question is too long to answer here, but you should already know the answer if you're developing on SSIS.  The next thing I'd check is the version of SSIS installed in BIDS.  Open it up and go to  Help -> About.  In Installed Products, SQL Server Integration Services should be v10.50.xxxx.xx.  That's 2008 R2.  Ideally you should have the same version completely, so you may need to install SP2 on your workstation.

Comment: You likely have a conflict between the dtsinstall.exe for the 2012 and the 2008. Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24006726/181965)

Comment: Let me know if specifying the full/correct path to dtsinstall resolved the issue

Comment: @billinkc Im using command like this: 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe" "E:\UAT_Deployment_Packages\Data_Final.SSISDeploymentManifest" Its showing package deplyment and validation success, however the packages are not getting installed into the desired folder...why? Is something missing? or I need to take care of some special things? Should I try like this : "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe" "E:\UAT_Deployment_Packages\Data_Final.SSISDeploymentManifest"

Answer (score 0):

you could not deploy packages or project that created from higher version VS to lower unmatched version of SSMS, usually SSMS2012-VS2012, SSMS2014-VS2013.

And the @@version is session scoped, make sure you connection to the correct instance then `select @@version`